# Is there a way I can set specific subclasses to have specific values relative to a variable in the parent class?

Tags: java

I am building a "Kennel" that takes dogs and cats.  I am relatively new to java so I al still trying to figure out the basics of Object Oriented Programming and am using this little project as a sort of lesson.  I have KennelPoly as a regular class, Pet as a parent class, and Dog and Cat as two separate classes that extend Pet.  The goal is to have the console read "I am a dog/cat and my name is ." followed by the sound that the animal makes, either "woof" or "meow".  My question is how to I make it so that the dog says woof and the cat says meow without having that information in the constructor?  Is there a way I can make it so that everything that uses the Dog class uses the string "woof" while the cat uses the string "meow"?  It would be simpler to just have the information in the constructor, but I know how to do that already and wanted to try it this way.  I tried the logical things I could think of, such as if statements, but found that (at least the way I was doing it) you cannot compare classes.  As of right now my program prints "I am null and my name is "  I am still working on getting it to print the type and am not quite sure how to do that, but one problem at a time.
Below is my basic class, KennelPoly;

```
public class KennelPoly {

    public KennelPoly() {
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("KennelPoly");
        
        Pet[] pets = new Pet[10];
        pets[0] = new Cat("Princess");
        pets[1] = new Dog("Max");
        pets[2] = new Cat("Pepper");
        pets[3] = new Cat("Monday");
        
        for (Pet pet : pets) {
            if (pet != null) {
                pet.print();
                pet.makeSound();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my pet class

```
public class Pet {
    private String type;
    private String name;
    private String sound;
    
    public Pet() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void makeSound() {
//      System.out.println
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("I am a " + type + " and my name is " + getName());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

This is the dog class, which does not have much in it.

```
public class Dog extends Pet {

    public Dog(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
    }

}
```

And this is the final Cat class

```
public class Cat extends Pet {

    public Cat(String name) {
        this.setName(name);

    }

}
```

Comment: I think you are referring to the use of 'inheritance' and 'super' keyword, take a look at this:
https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_keyword_super.asp

Answer (score 0):

Make dogs be responsible for making their own noise:

```
public class Dog extends Pet {
    @Override public void makeSound() {
        System.out.println("Woof!");
    }
}
```

then, while we're at it, let's *demand* that all subclasses of Pet must explicitly take responsibility:

```
public abstract class Pet {
    public abstract void makeSound();
}
```

The `abstract` tells java that all pets can make sound, but `Pet` (the class) doesn't actually know how to do it; each subtype of it will have to specify. java will enforce this (can't make a subclass of Pet without it having a `makeSound` method). Because of this, `new Pet()` is now impossible, but that's a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

So, following your concept since you said you're a beginner and maybe some answers seem alien to you, here is a direct follow up with your own concept and we will still achieve the same result, meanwhile it's will really be cool to learn from other advance answers also.

> Your KennelPoly class:

```
public class KennelPoly {
    public KennelPoly() {
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("KennelPoly");

        Pet[] pets = new Pet[10];
        pets[0] = new Cat("Princess");
        pets[1] = new Dog("Max");
        pets[2] = new Cat("Pepper");
        pets[3] = new Cat("Monday");

        for (Pet pet : pets) {
            if (pet != null) {
                pet.print();
                pet.makeSound();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Your Pet class:

```
public class Pet {
    private String type;
    private String name;
    private String sound;

    public Pet() {}

    public void makeSound() {
      System.out.println(getSound());
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("I am a " + getType() + " and my name is " + getName());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getSound() {
        return sound;
    }

    public void setSound(String sound) {
        this.sound = sound;
    }
}
```

> Your Dog class:

```
public class Dog extends Pet {

    public Dog(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
        this.setType("Dog");
        this.setSound("woof");
    }

}
```

And finally your cat class:

```
public class Cat extends Pet {

    public Cat(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
        this.setType("Cat");
        this.setSound("meow");
    }

}
```

Apparently you're just missing some getters and setters and also not parsing some info via the constructors of the sub-classes, just pay attention to what you're doing.

While this is straight forward, this is really not OOP, it's too tightly coupled and I will suggest you do something like what @rzwitserloot did.
Let each subclass be responsible for their own behaviour.

So, you could have something like below:

> Your pet class:

```
public abstract class Pet
 {
   public abstract void print();
   public abstract void makeSound();
 }
```

> Your Dog and Cat classes:

```
public class Dog extends Pet {
   private String name;
   
   public Dog(String name) {
        this.name = name;
   }

   @Override
   public void print() {
    System.out.println("I am a Dog and my name is " + this.name);
   }

   @Override
   public void makeSound() {
     System.out.println("woof");
   }
}


public class Cat extends Pet {
   private String name;

   public Cat(String name) {
        this.name = name;
   }

   @Override
   public void print() {
    System.out.println("I am a Cat and my name is " + this.name);
   }

   @Override
   public void makeSound() {
     System.out.println("meoww");
   }
}
```

Hopefully this two concepts makes it clear to you what you're doing now.
Note: There are still many ways to get this working...like using the

interface concept.

Adios.